# How to add comments to solidworks variable file?

Tags: solidworks

When using an external .txt file to define global variables for SolidWorks 2021, can one add comments to this file, and what is the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works the same way as VBA - just add an apostrophe, so, for example:

```
"Length" = 5mm 'Comment
```

This will then be visible in the "Comments" column within the Equation Manager, too.

Comment: What about comment only lines? I believe I am having an issue due to this

Comment: Just add a dummy variable? ``"Comment1" = 0mm 'Commentary``

Comment: Ah, that's ugly. Thanks anyway.